# Using Arrays to find Highest Number

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, int

So i would like to change this to show me the highest number not in what list the number is in. So basically i would like it to figure out the position of that number then print out what that number is.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TwoArrays
{
  public static void main (String args [] )
  {
    Random r = new Random();
    int rangeMin = 0;
    int rangeMax = 50;

    ArrayList<Double> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (int i =0;i<5;i++) 
    {
      double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
      arrayList1.add(randomValue); 
    }

    for (int i =0;i<5;i++)  
    {
      double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
      arrayList2.add(randomValue ); 
    }


    Double maxInArray1 = Collections.max(arrayList1);
    Double maxInArray2 = Collections.max(arrayList2);

    if (maxInArray1>maxInArray2)
    {  
      System.out.println("first array have max");
    }
    else  if(maxInArray1<maxInArray2)
    {
      System.out.println("second array have max");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("the max of second and first array is identical");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the biggest number or which list the biggest number is in?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what the biggest number is between the two lists

Comment: Thanks CollinD for the organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Double maxOfBoth = Math.max(maxInArray1, maxInArray2);
```

That will give you the biggest number between `arrayList1` and `arrayList2`

Comment: Straight after you create the `maxInArray2` variable